# Is there a way to upload images to and load from firebase using axios?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, express, axios

I am working on a react-native app that makes calls to a REST API I made with Express. I want to be able to upload an image to Fire Base from the app (or from my Express back end, whichever is easier) and then store the image URL in mongoDB. Right now, I have routes written in my backend that gets all image url's, adds an image URL to database (takes in URL from request body), and deletes an image url. The problem is that I do not know how to upload the image to Firebase and how to get the url to pass through the body of the request to my API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to upload image with **axios** where your header should support binaries

```
 headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
```

[here](https://gist.github.com/AshikNesin/e44b1950f6a24cfcd85330ffc1713513) there is a good **axios** example to start with